# How to prevent WebBrowser control to lose web state while navigate to other WindowPhone Page?

Tags: .net, windows-phone-7, webbrowser-control, tombstoning

I have one page with WebBrowser control in it.
When I Navigate with `NavigationService.Navigate()` (next page xaml) and then back the WebBrowser control loses his web state.

How can I make the WebBrowser control not unload when navigate to other page?
The solution can be put the WebBrowser control outside.  I saw there is something in c#/silverlight called AdornerLayer.

Please advice/help.
Thanks.

Comment: Hi Ishai, haven`t tried it, but try to use the PhoneApplicationService.State Dictionary to store the webbrowser state when you navigate from it and load the state if you navigate back to it.

Comment: Thanks
But unfortunately it's not enough for me, 
I don't want even reload the web page.

Answer (score 1):

If the web site is under your control, then you could use cookies to store whatever state you have, and then re-load it when the user returns. If not, and you just want to store which page the user was viewing before, then you can store the URL in [`PhoneApplicationPage.State`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.controls.phoneapplicationpage.state%28VS.92%29.aspx) and then restore it in the **OnNavigatedTo** override for the page.

Comment: Thanks
But unfortunately it's not enough for me, 
I don't want even reload the web page.

Comment: If you're navigating forwards to a page, and then backwards to this page with the WebBrowser control on it, the only option you have is to reload the web page. There is no way for you to cache application pages in the navigation history.